# Tricky Recursion: Subtracting values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Let's say I have a dictionary and a value:

```
dic = {'1': 10, '2': 20, '3': 30}
value1 = 25
```

I would like to get the following:

```
result = {'1': 0, '2': 5, '3': 30}
```

And let's say I've been given another value:

```
value2 = 30
```

I will get the following:

```
result2 = {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 5}
```

As you can see, it skips the first keys as the values are zero and keep iterating until the value has been fully subtracted from the dictionary.

Here is some sudo code:

```
value - a['1'] = 15 (remainder)
15 - a['2'] = -5  <- recursion or loop should stop as remainder is less than zero

return result = {'1': 0, '2': 5, '3': 30}
```

Caveats:

- the dictionary is not ordered
- don't subtract from a value that is already zero
- **the dictionary can have many keys**

Comment: Dictionaries don't really have "first" keys, what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Pleas provide a [mcve] for what you've tried so far. Note, since you've tagged 2 different versions of python: In anything but the few most recent python versions, dictionary order is not guaranteed. If you want to operate in this way, you need another data structure, like an `ordereddict()`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a hash in Redis, storing the number of items that are in stock. When I sell something, it should subtract them from their 'buckets'. Then, I will run some sort of query that will check the values for all these items, and set their sold_out field to True.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `'3'` in `result` for `value1` be `25`, since the the chain of the computation would be `|10-25| = 15 (but register 0, since 25 > 10)`, `|20-15| = 5`, `|30-5| = 25`?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  "How can I do this using recursion" is a tutorial-level question, off-topic fro Stack Overflow.  However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Try converting this into three problems and see if you are stuck with any of them:  `foo(redis) -> ordered list`; `bar(ordered list, sold) -> new ordered list`; `baz(ordered list) -> redis`

Comment: @Cireo I figured that there are many ways to do this, but I was so interested in figuring out how to do this that I posted the question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered in any Python versions < 3.7. Since the order of the input matters in this problem, you can create a list of tuples for input, and form a dictionary as the returned result:

```
dic = {'1': 10, '2': 20, '3': 30}
value1 = 25
def new_d(d, c):
  [a, b], *_c = d
  return {a:0 if c > b else b-c, **({} if not _c else new_d(_c, 0 if b > c else abs(b-c)))}

print(new_d(list(dic.items()), value1))
```

Output:

```
{'1': 0, '2': 5, '3': 30}
```

With `value2`:

```
value2 = 30
print(new_d(list(dic.items()), value2))
```

Output:

```
{'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 30}
```

---

```
dic, value1 = {'1': 0, '2': 20, '3': 30, '4': 40, '5': 50}, 55
print(new_d(list(dic.items()), value1))
```

Output:

```
{'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 35, '5': 50}
```

Edit: in-depth version:

```
def new_d(d, c):
   [a, b], *_c = d
   result = {a:0 if c > b else b-c}
   if not _c:
      return result
   return {**result, **new_d(_c, 0 if b > c else abs(b-c))}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer when the dictionary has only 3 keys. When i use a value of 55 from dic = {'1': 0, '2': 20, '3': 30, '4': 40, '5': 50}, i get: {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 35, '5': 15}. thank you for your help btw

Comment: Btw, if you have non-one liner version, feel free to share it as it will help me understand what you did here a little bit more. Thank you again Ajax

Comment: @Anthony No problem, please see my recent edit. Please let me know if the edit helps you or if you have any questions.

Comment: Ajax, not related to this question, but how did figure it out so easy? What do you suggest I should do to get better. maybe you can recommend some sources that you used for getting better. I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Anthony No problem. Recursion follows a specific pattern of a base case (a `return` statement that does not include a call to the function itself), and any recursive calls to the function itself. That said, there are a variety of standard recursive patterns for handling problems such as factorial and Fibonacci computations, binary tree traversal, etc. I have found it helpful to familiarize myself with those patterns, and then expand upon them to solve slightly different problems such as the one in your case. See [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/recursion.html) for examples

Comment: @Anthony The link above shows, with clean pseudo-code, some of the common recursive patterns. In the case of your computational problem, I found it to be most like the factorial pattern, as we are ultimately subtracting from the value passed in, and continuing the chain of calls only if there are still elements left in `d`. Unpacking at each call (`[a, b], *_c = d`) will store the remaining data in `_c`, and a check if `_c` is an empty list satisfies the base case. If `_c` is empty, then we return an empty dictionary. If not, create a dict with `a` and `b`, and call again.

Comment: @Anthony Please let me know if that helps